# How to use mongoimport command in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run `./mongoimport -d crunchbase -c companies companies.json`, 
but I am getting the following error:-

> open companies.json:  no such file or directory is found

I am running the above command from

```
mongod/bin
```

Can anyone suggest me what error I am doing?

Comment: Is there a file named companies.json on that directory?

Comment: yes ,but still error is coming

Comment: I think you need --file to read from a file